# Trying to insert image/xml file as blob in cassandra database

Tags: java, xml, cassandra

Actually I need to insert xml file in cassandra database. So initially am trying to insert image as a blob content later I change the code to insert xml but am facing issues in insert and retrieve the blob content as image. Can anyone suggest which is the best practice to insert image/xml file in cassandra database.

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:/Users/anand.png");
byte[] b= new byte[fis.available()+1];
int length=b.length;
fis.read(b);

System.out.println(length);

ByteBuffer buffer =ByteBuffer.wrap(b);

PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("insert into usersimage (firstname,lastname,age,email,city,length,image) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(ps);

int age=22;
//System.out.println(buffer);

session.execute( boundStatement.bind( "xxx","D",age,"xxx@gmail.com","xxx",length,buffer));

//session.execute(  boundStatement.bind( buffer, "Andy", length));



 PreparedStatement ps1 = session.prepare("select * from usersimage where email =?");
    BoundStatement boundStatement1 = new BoundStatement(ps1);
    ResultSet rs =session.execute(boundStatement1.bind("ramya1@gmail.com"));

    ByteBuffer bImage=null; 

    for (Row row : rs) {
     bImage = row.getBytes("image") ;
     length=row.getInt("length");
    }

byte image[]= new byte[length];
image=Bytes.getArray(bImage);

HttpServletResponse response = null;
@SuppressWarnings("null")
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("image/png");
response.setContentLength(image.length);
out.write(image);
```

Am facing issues while retrieving the blob content as image. could anyone please help me on this.

Comment: try using datastax OGM library for DB operation. Also when you say 'facing issues', describe what exactly the issues are, such as errors, stack trace

Comment: @monish Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, am getting the null value while retieveing the record

Answer (score 0):

- You are *inserting* data to an email and *selecting* from another;
- A better way to read the bytes of an image would be:

  ```
  BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/anand.png"));
  ByteArrayOutputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ImageIO.write(originalImage, "png", imageStream );
  imageStream.flush();
  byte[] imageInByte = imageStream.toByteArray();
  ```

Comment: actually am inserting one record and based on that inserted record am selecting the record.